# How Figma copies to clipboard and then understands the content behind it even is empty

Tags: figma, webflow

I was wondering how Figma or Webflow or Framer or similar tools understand and copy to clipboard that is empty, but when you go to another tab or the app from the web you can paste the content, what they do, how they handle it? For example I have seen websites having components that you can copy and they can be added into those tools?

I tried to understand the clipboard if the content can be hidden or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's an object. First copy a Webflow or any component, and paste it into this to see what's behind it.

https://evercoder.github.io/clipboard-inspector/